# it is a timeout error when sending mail by using smtp.office365.com in Opencart

Tags: php, smtp, office365, opencart

I have recently migrated the OpenCart from Lunix server to Windows Server (WAMP)
Also the mail settings have been changed from Mail to SMTP (office365.com)

My Opencart version is 2.0.2.0 and the SMTP settings are

**Mail Protocol:** SMTP

**Mail Parameters:** -finfo@somedomain.com

**SMTP Hostname:** smtp.office365.com

**SMTP Username:** shop@somedomain.com

**SMTP Password:** mypassword

**SMTP Port:** 587

**SMTP Timeout:** 5

I found a strange scenario for mail function.
I always got the following errors when I register a new user. Then when I click the "back" button to register a new user again, change another email, it works fine. However when I wait for an hour and do it again. the problem has happen again.

It is an error message:

> *Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Handshake timed out in C:\wamp64\www\system\modification\system\library\mail.php on line 237
>   Notice: Error: EHLO not accepted from server! in
>   C:\wamp64\www\system\modification\system\library\mail.php on line 254*

The code on

```
line 237 --> stream_socket_enable_crypto($handle, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
line 253 --> if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
line 254 --> trigger_error('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
line 255 --> exit();
line 256 --> }
```

I have no idea. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `ssl://` or `tls://` to your host, like

**SMTP Hostname:** ssl://smtp.office365.com

or

**SMTP Hostname:** tls://smtp.office365.com

Depends on which protocol your 587 port supports.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I tired to change both settings, but it doesn't work.The send mail still fail in the first time.

Comment: Then it's definitely not an opencart issue. It's all about WAMP. Maybe try to add in server config `extension=php_openssl.dll`, and check. If this dll exist. But youse windows and WAMP to host website - bad idea. Windows in not suitable for web hosting, have many 
restrictions